# Looking for a way to implement a polymorphic view in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, polymorphism

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC Core web app that would have a lot of similar views. Each view is just a simple form that has a list of label&control pairs.
An "Object" editor template has been built in order to generate the content of such views automatically based on view model properties.
Each view would basically have just one line of code:
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
Each view model is derived from a base class.

Is there a way to get rid of duplicate views and controller actions?

Ideally, I'd like to have just one view where the model is the base model class and one controller action that would receive that base model.

Comment: You would do that using Partial views/View Components.

Answer (score 0):

Himanshu's comment steered me to use Partials for the child classes and use the base class as the model for the main views.  You may be able to just use reflection/property annotation to populate the views according to the given Model, though I have not tried it.
What I have tried successfully is using a base class that is not abstract and thus will not duplicate properties in the child classes, then using generics like...

```
List<T> GetChildClasses<T>() where T : BaseClass;
```

which is called by the controller method and supplies the View Model, and then displaying like this...

```
@model MyApp.Models.BaseClass
<div class="show_base_class_properties_here">
</div>
@if(Model is ChildClass)
{
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ChildPartial", Model);
}
<div class="whatever_comes_next">
</div>
```

I suspect there is a better way but this works.  Apparently there can only be one `@model` in a view file.